# AngularJS foreach - producing numerous null for unassigned values

Tags: angularjs

I have a array variable `viewedprofiles= [];` initialized.

I'll be assigning the profiles that have been viewed to this `viewedprofiles` array. Now if I try to display it (By assigning it to a $scope), I get NULL for other values that have not got assigned or touched.

```
  var viewedprofiles= [];               

    angular.forEach(profiles, function(value, key){         

        if(value.viewed== "yes") {
            viewedprofiles[value.id] = TRUE;
        }       

    });
```

The output of `viewedprofiles` is as follows

```
 [NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,TRUE]
```

**Output explanation :**

Since the 9th id's profile `viewed` value was `yes`, the output returned TRUE at the 9th element of the `viewedprofiles` array.

Nothing wrong actually.

But I was wondering as far as the above code, the id was TRUE for 9th element. What if the id was some large number say 15640, Will there be 15639 `NULL`s before `TRUE`? Am I doing anything wrong or is there another way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
What I was trying to do was basically wrong at the assigning part. I should push the element instead of assigning.

The following worked.

```
angular.forEach(profiles, function(value, key){         

    if(value.viewed== "yes") {
        viewedprofiles.push(value.id);
    }       

}, viewedprofiles);
```